# Add leading zeroes to a moment.js time

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, momentjs

I'm currently using moment.js to handle the displaying of time in a node.js application - is there a way I can ALWAYS have the date formatted with leading zeroes, and atleast two characters wide?

So for 9 days, 1 hour, 12 minutes and 23 seconds

```
09:01:12:23
```

or for 1 minute

```
00:00:01:00
```

Thanks anyone that can help

---

I'm calculating the time between two things in a database, and then sending it to moment.js in seconds.

`duration.html(difference.add(1, "seconds").format("d:hh:mm:ss"));`

Essentially I'd like to enforce that even when days are 0 they be displayed, along with the leading zero for single digit numbers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [moment-duration format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plug-in:

Use the [`trim`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#trim) option to show units that have no value. As the docs says:

> Leading tokens are automatically trimmed when they have no value. To stop that behavior, set `{ trim: false }`.

Here a working example:

```js
var d1 = moment.duration({
  seconds: 23,
  minutes: 12,
  hours: 1,
  days: 9
});
var d2 = moment.duration({
  minutes: 1
});
console.log(d1.format('DD:HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(d2.format('DD:HH:mm:ss', { trim: false }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that moment-duration-format is different from momentjs which is why trim doesn't appear anywhere on the momentjs site. Thanks VincenzoC for { trim: false }

Comment: @mcmacerson I know that [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) is a momentjs plug-in, I've edited my answer to make it clearer. As a side note, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1048 to plan duration format integration in moment core). I'm glad my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

try 
   `moment(your_date, "your_date_format").format("DD:HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: That wont work because looking at the question the OP wants the duration not to display the date

Comment: ohh.. I'm confused. You mean, 9 is no of days and not date? right?

Comment: Question was updated ya thats it its not a date just days

Answer (score 0):

use format letter double times in format instead of one.

e.g

```
moment(new Date()).format("DD MMM YY")
```

will give leading zero, but

```
moment(new Date()).format("D MMM YY")
```

won't

Answer (score -3):

Use this:

```
function addZeros(d,h,m,s){
  return  ("0"+d).substr(-2) + ":" +("0"+h).substr(-2) + ":"+("0"+m).substr(-2) + ":" +("0"+s).substr(-2);
}
```

Comment: Use this for what?